# Unit testing of PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, testing, plsql

I would like to ask if you write/make any unit tests on your database and if yes what are yours experiences?
Do the tests are worth the effort? You test only high-level procedure or also functions? What are the best practises?

Comment: A good question, but not a good fit for this site.  You'll likely get a lot of opinions and no clear right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Testing best practices for PL/SQL or any DB for that matter:

- Software 101- The earlier you catch a bug, less expensive it is to fix.  By that adage every code going into production should be tested and PL/SQL is no exception.  Testing is always worth the effort - no ambiguities there
- Database testing should be done at two levels - for the data and about the data
- For the data - this includes metrics of data loaded and the process- eg - define sample data set and calculate how much expected counts will be in target tables after the test case is executed.
- Secondly Performance test cases - this test the process eg - if you load full production set, how long that takes.  Again you don't want to uncover performance issue in production
- About the data - this is more business testing, whether the data loaded is as per expected functionality - eg - if if you are aggregating sales rep to their parent companies, is the one to many relationship between company and sales rep valid after you run the test case.
- Always create a test query which results in a number, eg - select count of sales rep which are not associated to any company.  if the count > 0 then it is a failure
- It's a good idea to put test cases, their results, test query and actual result in a table so that you can review them and slice and dice if required.
- You can write a SP to automate running the test query from the table and this be repeated very easily and even can be embedded in a batch or a GUI screen